# Rebooting embedded device when enabled debug infromation

Tags: c, stack-corruption

I'm working with SDK for some embedded device. There are some proprietary RTOS and application code. I have found some bug in this sdk: device is rebooted during printing some debug information (via macros DEV_PRINTF).

Bug is reproduced (but not always) only in one place: when calling DEV_PRINTF (in my example i have commented this line). In other functions this macros working fine.

Below is placed problem code:

```
#define DEV_PRINTF printf_realization

static int txrx_config(struct device *dev, int size, int loop, const     UINT8 *buffer)
{
 struct private *p = (struct private *)dev->priv;
 if (p == NULL)
  return -1;

 DEV_PRINTF("%s: p = %x\n", __FUNCTION__, p); // p is correct in all cases

  // BUG: when DEV_PRINTF is uncommented in that place than device is rebooted.
  /*DEV_PRINTF("In %s method %d %d\n",
          __FUNCTION__, p->rx, p->tx);*/

  if ((!p->force_tx_rx) && (!p->auto_tx_rx))
  {
      return txrx_config_group_one(dev, size, loop);
  }
     else
      {
          return txrx_config_group_two(dev, size, loop, buffer);
      }

}
```

Below is placed log when bug was reproduced:

```
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In txrx_config: method 0 1
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In txrx_config: method 1 1
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In txrx_config: method 1 0
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In txrx_config: method 0 1
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In txrx_config: method 1 0
txrx_config: p = 0x80772c00
In
```

So main question: Where i have to find the problem -  in the printf_realization function (but i don't think so, becuase this function working fine in other part of the sdk) or maybe is it stack corruption (for example writing out of range in the array) in some places in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: As you said: it can come from anywhere in your SDK... What is `__FUNCTION__` ? Does `printf_realization` checks for NULL pointer ? Also consider that printing traces changes the timing of the process so it can reveal bugs in other components of the embedded system.

Comment: @Coconop __FUNCTION__
is a preprocessor define which is predefined in the gcc so i don't think it's a problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Max Three questions: -1- Does it always print "In" before the reboot or random number of characters of the string to be printed? -2- What happens when you replace the (commented out) DEV_PRINTF with a, say, 50ms sleep? -3- What happens when you replace the (commented out) DEV_PRINTF with the following: int a = p->rx; int b = p->tx;

Comment: @simurg -1- Yes, it always print "ln" before the reboot. 
-2- When i've replaced the  (commented out) DEV_PRINTF with 50ms sleep bug doesn't reproduce. 
-3- When i've replaced the  (commented out) DEV_PRINTF with the following: int a = p->rx; int b = p->tx - bug doesn't reproduce. 
I think i may to try use variable a and b as parameters for the macros DEV_PRINTF instead of p->rx and p->tx, because p->rx and p->tx  are unsigned char types. Then trying reproduce bug. Thanks!